# Is there a way to Highlight org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I am currently working on a dialog which shows a ProgressBar and some buttons at the bottom. Occasionally, the ProgressBar will pause and wait for user input via the buttons. I would like to highlight the buttons at this moment, ideally via the frame. I can make the background blink without any problems, but I would like to use effects that are related to the operating system, especially since I already work with SWT. I can find little to nothing online on this topic.

That's the code I prototyped for the blinking-effect so far

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Display.getDefault().syncExec(() -> button.setBackground(new Color(new RGB(255, 0, 0))));
    sleep(100);
    Display.getDefault()
        .syncExec(() -> button.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND)));
    sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: `setBackground` on a `Button` doesn't work on some platforms. It works on macOS but I believe it doesn't work on Windows. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21660030/2670892)

Comment: It works on Windows, already tested it, but the thing is that I don't want the blinking effect over the background, but preferably over the border of the button

Comment: There is no control of that at all. The question I linked tries to mess around using a label and images to simulate a button, maybe you could do something like that. But the 'button' will look wrong on other platforms (macOS buttons don't even have a border)

Comment: Well, guess that I have to do something different then, but thank you very much