# Changing Button color using CSS in E4

Tags: css, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm trying to change the color of the button in E4 application using CSS styling.
I tried CSS style

```
Button {
        background-color: #FF0000;
        color: #48CCCD;
       }
```

I could see only background of the button getting changed, not the foreground.

Any idea, how to change the foreground color using e4 css?

(OS: Windows 7)

Comment: I think this depends on what the native button control SWT uses supports. On my Mac the foreground color works but the background color does not work.

Comment: How to add the style for button which apply for all windows , Ubuntu , Mac ?

Comment: What I am saying is that styling buttons doesn't seem to work properly on several platforms. On the Mac the background does not work, on Windows the foreground does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS selector is not working because in Windows is not possible to set the background color for a button. Unfortunately it is the same for the foreground color.

See [Eclipse documentation (4.4) > Control.setBackground(.)](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FControl.html&anchor=setBackground(org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color))

You'll read:

```
For example, on Windows the background of a Button cannot be changed.
```

See also:

- [Stackoverflow question 3312102](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312102/changing-org-eclipse-swt-widgets-background-color-in-windows)
- [Stackoverflow question 4747562](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747562/how-to-set-swt-button-foreground-color)