# SWT Button - Remove button background

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a button that looks like this:
[image]

I want to remove the button background.. That is, the image will be the button.
Here is my code:

```
Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
button.setToolTipText("Email Settings...");
button.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Settings.class, "settings1616.png"));
button.setBounds(494, 26, 28, 25);
```

I have tried..

```
button.setBackground(null);
button.setBackgroundImage(null);
```

But it does not remove anything.
Thanks!

Comment: What platform is this? On some platforms (Windows for example) you can't change a button background like this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3312102/2670892

Comment: I am using Windows. Is this possible via Macintosh?

Comment: or just use a clickable JLabel with ImageIcon

Comment: Okay, I will give that a try.

Comment: A quick test shows setBackground does not work in Macs.

Comment: You can't mix Swing (JLabel) with SWT easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try using SWT Image HyperLink ,this doest have button background and it solves your purpose.

Add `org.eclipse.ui.forms` as a dependency.

`ImageHyperlink hyperlink = new ImageHyperlink(parentComposite, SWT.NONE);
 hyperlink.setImage("image location");`

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Tool Item with a Tool bar. here http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet18.java is a snippet that will help.
And use

```
toolitem.setImage(Your_image);
```

This works in mac too!

Answer (score 0):

Think outside the box.

```
Label button = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
button.setToolTipText("Email Settings...");
button.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Settings.class, "settings1616.png"));
button.setBounds(494, 26, 28, 25);
button.setCursor(Display.getDefault().getCursor(SWT.CURSOR_HAND)); 
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Do your thing
    }
});
```