# Set background color for scrollbar

Tags: java, swt

I use `ScrolledComposite` and I can't find how to change background of ScrollBars. Is it possible to change background of ScrollBars?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I use Mac OS X, Windows and Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** No.

**Long answer:** No, because SWT is built on top of OS native UI. You can't change the native looks and feels.

<strike>**Although...:** You can "hack" it by painting on top of the scrollbar control. In my opinion, that's a lot of hussle, and it's not worth it.</strike>

**Other solutions:** Use JavaFX. Almost fully customizable.

**Similar questions:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312102/changing-org-eclipse-swt-widgets-background-color-in-windows), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747562/how-to-set-swt-button-foreground-color), [also here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/133575/)

Comment: I think even painting is not possible, or how would you 'paint on top of the scroll bar'?

Comment: @RudigerHerrmann I tried painting on top of the scroll. You were right, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

No, setting the background color of scroll bars is not possible in SWT.

SWT is designed to use the native GUI library of the respective platform and it is this library that defines the look and feel of the widgets, including the colors of scroll bars.